# SSRS2008 - SELECT in a CASE...WHEN...THEN

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am using a hidden internal Parameter (@DoorHelper) to check if another parameter I am using(@Door) contains a special value I use to represent 'global'('9999') and return all Doors in that case.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN ('9999'+'-'+ RIGHT(Unknown1,1) in (@Door)) 
THEN (SELECT DISTINCT [Zone]+' - '+CAST([OfficeID] as char(5)) FROM [ADB].[dbo].[ZoneByOffice])
ELSE (@Door)
END AS ZoneID
FROM [ADB].[dbo].[EventLog]
```

Issue is, returning more than 1 result from a THEN seems to throw errors.

How can I reform this SQL to do what I want it to?

Comment: What does `@Door` look like? Is it a CSV list that you are trying to use as an actual value list for the `IN(…)` operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP 1`

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ('9999'+'-'+ RIGHT(Unknown1,1) in (@Door)) 
        THEN (SELECT TOP 1 [Zone]+ ' - '+ CAST([OfficeID] as char(5)) FROM [ADB].[dbo].[ZoneByOffice])
        ELSE (@Door)
    END AS ZoneID
FROM [ADB].[dbo].[EventLog]
```

or you limit the result set with `WHERE` condition by unique field if any, to guarantee it never returns more than one row.

Comment: Can I use Distinct along with your suggestion? And from my understanding, if I use TOP1 like that I might get lots of the same [Zone] instead of a set of all available ones?

Comment: `TOP 1` will return just one, so `DISTINCT` does not make much sense in this case.

Comment: @Kitler - if this is not what you want, please show a sample input and expected output for the query.

Comment: I meant like SELECT DISTINCT CASE, although I suppose TOP 1 would still return the same thing in the inner SELECT.

Comment: @Kitler - I don't understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: @Kitler: In any event, the subquery **must** return no more than one value. Whether you ensure that with `DISTINCT CASE …` or with `TOP 1` is up to you. The latter is probably better, though, because with DISTINCT you'd have an absolutely unnecessary distinct sort, which would affect the performance negatively.

Comment: thanks for your replies, turns out i was just overcomplicating things, abandoned this approach and just used a WHERE CASE instead of another dataset

Comment: @Kitler -  glad you found a solution. I believe I answered your question the best I could. :)